# elisp search-forward with regexp and spec. chars return nil

Tags: elisp

emacs 25.1

I have string:

```
<p>more complex non Q and A HTML code here.</p><table class="waffle" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><thead><tr><th
```

And if use in emacs regexp-builder with the next regexp: `"<table .*?>"`

it's success found text:

```
<table class="waffle" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
```

OK. But when I use same regexp in elisp by function **search-forward** nothing found (return nil)

```
      (setq test-start-point (search-forward "<table .*?>" nil t))
```

**test-start-point** = nil.

Why?

Comment: Did you really mean to use `search-forward` instead of `re-search-forward` when setting `test-start-point`?

Comment: "re-search-forward" is work! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`search-forward` searches exact matches.  In your case, you want to search a regular expression pattern, so you want to use `re-search-forward` instead.